# Controls positioning under the navigation bar issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, screen-orientation, nslayoutconstraint

I have a question on Auto layout. I'm using xib files and I have a view controller like this.

[image]

Its embedded inside a `UINavigationController` so I have the button positioned with a *Top Space to Superview* constraint.

The problem is when I rotate the device, it looks like this.

[image]

As you can see that constraint still keeps its original value so there's a big gap between the navigation bar edge and the button in landscape mode.

How can I make the button position close to the navigation bar like when its in the portrait and have it that way in both portrait and landscape modes? I'm using Xcode 6 by the way.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the multiplier value of your constraint ?

Comment: The multiplier value is 1.

Comment: Truy to set it to zero

Comment: Xcode doesn't allow me to set it to 0. The lowest I can go is 0.1 but it doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest you to switch to visual format with following string "V:|(button)", this should work

Comment: I'm getting an error saying **Type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' does not conform to protocol 'ArrayLiteralConvertible'**. [Here](http://pastie.org/9599101) is my code right now. I haven't done auto layout using VFL before.

Comment: the last parameter should be a `NSDictionary`. Have a look to following guide  https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to define your auto layout top margin constraints in your Xib file, you can add the following code in the ViewController's class file relative to your Xib:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.respondsToSelector("edgesForExtendedLayout") {
        edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    }
}
```

Simple. But the problem there is that you won't be able to have a translucent navigation bar.

Fortunately, there are several alternatives to this. You can define your auto layout top margin as relative to your Top Layout Guide (not to your view) with Storyboard or with code.

If you move to **Storyboard**, click on the Pin button, select your top margin constraint and choose The Top Layout Guide (see image below).

[image]

If you decide to define all your `UIButton`'s constraints with code, you can use **Visual Format Language** as indicated in the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view.addSubview(button)

        var viewsDict = ["button" : button, "topLayoutGuide" : topLayoutGuide]

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[topLayoutGuide]-20-[button]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[button]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    }

}
```

Finally, there is a fourth (kind of mixed) way to perform what you want to do. Set your constraints in your Xib, drag your top margin constraint and your `UIButton` to your view controller class (name them `topConstraint` and `button`) and set your code as the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
        view.removeConstraint(topConstraint)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you once again! I'm using xib files so I adopted the last one. Works like a charm.

Comment: The forth option is really helpful.